# IFTTT recipe api - is there documentation to create recipe using API call

Tags: ifttt

I have already created triggers and actions for IFTTT channel. Now I want to create a recipe using these triggers and actions, but I want to do it not through Maker, but using an API call. What would be the format of the API call (behind Maker UI) to create a recipe, I am seems to unable to see any documentation or examples?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There is a [documentation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/features.ifttt.com/developer_platform/ChannelDevelopmentGuidebook_02082016.pdf) for create / triggers and actions.

You need to create the API from your server like that:
`http://api.test.com:8080/ifttt/v1/triggers/{{triggers}}`

More information:

1. Login: https://developers.ifttt.com/channels/t4/triggers
2. Click triggers in left menu
3. Create trigger name
4. Then as the endpoint you need to give your api url.

Comment: the developers link now redirects to the partners part of IFTTT rather than a specific page

Comment: Yes @Mousey, they changed recently.

Answer (score 2):

Click the URL in your [maker settings](https://ifttt.com/services/maker/settings) to see IFTTT's description, which reads as follows, and shows your individual API key which must be used in your code:

> To trigger an Event  Make a POST or GET web request to: 
>   https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{event}/with/key/tIpcUAlqRkf8Mls9XepGN
>   With an optional JSON body of:

`{ "value1" : "", "value2" : "", "value3" : "" }`

> The data is completely optional, and you can also
>   pass value1, value2, and value3 as query parameters or form variables.
>   This content will be passed on to the Action in your Recipe.  You can
>   also try it with curl from a command line.

`curl -X POST https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{event}/with/key/tIpcUAlqRkf8Mls9XepGN`

Comment: question was about api for creating a recipe (applet) with given trigger and action, not signalling a trigger

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API. With old-type call there is internal API you can see REST calls like create/api/state whilst building a recipe, yet it might be protected from use by third party and I did not check the traffic of new applet maker platform. Note, if you are a partner you can embed your recipes into your apps. Upper tier customers are allowed to request new features (such as API or templates).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same, but after wasting hours, NO LUCK. So, I have decided to create one. This might be too late, but here's one repo of IFTTT boilerplate (https://github.com/Dipen-Dedania/ifttt-boilerplate) using NodeJS and express to create your own recipe (custom triggers and actions)